# How do I create non-local volume in docker compose?

Tags: docker

I'm experimenting with my fork of docker zfs plugin, to create separate filesystem for each volume. `docker volume create -d zfs my_volume` creates my_volume as expected, but

```
version: "3.9"

volumes:
  postgres_16:
    driver: zfs

services:
  postgres_16:
    # if you build image locally and tagged it as "postgres_mysql_fdw"
    #image: postgres_mysql_fdw

    # if you want to use prebuilt image
    image: registry.ctplt.ru/postgres:develop
    container_name: postgres_16
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - "./configs/postgresql/postgresql.conf:/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf"
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime"
      - "postgres_16:/var/lib/postgresql"
```

gives me an error

```
external volume "stagingc_postgres_16" not found
```

(COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME is set to stagingc, so stagingc_ prefix is quite what I've expected)

Is it possible to create a non-local type volume automatically by docker compose?